# How to style CodeIgniter form label

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am trying to change the color of the form labels and I was wondering how to do it.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('First Name'); 

$data = array(
  'class'=>'form-control',
  'name'=>'fname',
  'placeholder'=>'First Name'
);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add array of class or id to it.

Comment: i have tried to do that but I get errors

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: iv sorted it now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form open if you have a `id="exmaple"` In your css file have you tried

```
#example label {
  color: #222222;
}
```

You may need important

```
#example label {
  color: #222222 !important;
}
```

And looks like your mixing [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) code with [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) code bootstrap `col-md-6`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 2):

Use always `form_helper` way

```
$attributes = array(
        'class' => 'class-name-yours', // external or internal css
        'style' => 'color: #000;'     // or inline css, this is black color
);

echo form_label('First Name', 'firstname', $attributes);  //first name is form id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think best option is..

```
    <div id="firstname" style="color: orange;">
      <?php 
      echo form_label('First Name') ; 
      ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: using css file thinks better